# f.select does not update on false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
<%= f.label nil, "*Status" %><br \>
<%= f.select :full_time, [["Full Time", true], ["Daily Call", false]], :prompt => "-Select a Status-" %>
```

`:full_time` is a boolean (tinyint(1) in mysql).

The issue I'm having is that when I select "Full Time" or true, it will update the mysql db, but when I select "Daily Call" or false, it will not update the database at all.

Why is this happening and how should I fix this?? I'll provide more code on request.

*Additional info:*

As far as the controller, there is no code that involves `:full_time` .

It looks like this in the schema.rb: `t.boolean "full_time"`

Also, every other field is working fine in the form.

Comment: What does the controller see in `params[:your_model][:full_time]`?

Comment: Please share the involved controller and model.

Comment: Why not use a checkbox for a boolean?

Comment: Levi, the controller sees "true" when I select Full Time and "false" when I select Daily Call and submit it. 
Graeme, I'm doing this so that they could understand that it's either Full time or Daily Call... other than having people confused as to what the opposite of Full time might be.

Comment: The code depicted works fine for me, but I'm on Postgres. I would second the comment made by @PeterAlfvin – it'd be helpful if you posted the controller and model code.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I found this piece of code in my controller:

```
new_fields = Hash.new
@position.attributes = params[:position]
changed_fields = @position.changed
changed_fields.each do |f|
  if !@position[f].blank?
   new_fields[f] = @position[f]
  end
end
```

I realized that calling `@position[f].blank?` on a boolean that's false will return true.. hence why it wasn't being added.

For those that are curious how it wasn't working... it later checks the new_fields to see if it's empty to decide whether it wants to save the modified position or not.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: IMO, the answer to this question is a non-sequitur. While it resolved the circumstances surrounding your particular situation, what you've depicted is a fringe case. I'd be more helpful if you depicted your source code in the question itself.